# nginx regex not matching the url

Tags: nginx, regex

I have an issue with nginx, which after simplifying everything (just a single location directive) reduces to

```
location ~ ^/api/pages/user/.*$ {
  return 200 "This is a dummy response for /api/user/";
}
```

When access this location I get:

```
$>  curl -k https://local.example.com/api/pages/user/dqwdqw23rfweg
{"statusCode":404,"message":"Cannot GET /user","error":"Not Found"}
```

My first assumption was that something was just wrong with my config, so I simplified it even more:

```
location ~ ^/api/pages/user$ {
  return 200 "This is a dummy response for /api/user/";
}
```

and

```
$> curl -k https://local.example.com/api/pages/user
This is a dummy response for /api/user/
```

To me, that regex looks perfectly fine, but it is clear something is wrong? Any suggestions what my mistake is?

Comment: Clearly your configuration is more than just one simplified location statement, as illustrated by the JSON response for the 404 status. Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire configuration across all included files. If you want advice on why Nginx is [selecting a different location to process the request](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html#simple_php_site_configuration) you should edit your question and add the entire configuration.